# Read Single Column Excel Data, add into list

Tags: c#, excel, list, loops, arraylist

I have an excel sheet with a single column of data.

I've only really done it with a csv but I've forgotten how to do it with a single row. I can't seem to get it to work. What I have now with what I think is right but is not working.

```
            List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\vcl\CompletionTest.xlsx"));

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var value = reader[0].ToString();
            strList.Add(values[0]);
        }
```

Please and thank you!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: There are no errors, it just doesn't work. I would like to think there's something wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you are using C# in visual studio. Setup a breakpoint and check for value of var reader at runtime.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with `var line`

Comment: I am reading from the excel column.

Comment: Can you please tag with the language you are using? That will take care of a lot of guesswork and make it easier for experts in that language to find your question.

Comment: @teylyn Thank you. I have done necessary changes